# VS2017 add program to "open with" list

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In my projects, I use special editors for some file types (a special schema editor for XSDs and Qt Designer for UI Files). In VS2017, I can right click the files, select "open with" and add the editor and define it as default.

However, whenever I close VS, the assignment and editor is lost. I have to repeat this procedure every day, multiple times a day!

Is there a way to *permanently* add an editor to the editors list, and define it as standard, for all solutions (i.e. per user / per VS installation basis)?

Comment: Same problem here. I already searched a lot in every corner. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved itself. MS Visual Studio 2017 15.7.2 (maybe even 15.7.1) now permanently stores the added editors and defaults